# escaping the "insert mode" of the zsh vi-mode when using tmux

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'm using **zsh** with its **vi-mode** and the plugin **vi-mod**. I choose to
escape the insert mode with the combinaison of keys `jk`. At the begining,
the time allowed to put `k` with the `j` was too short, I set `export KEYTIMEOUT="30"` in my `.zsh` to solve this.

Unfortunately, I met the same probleme with **tmux**: the delay to type `k` with `j` is too short.. I've seen in some forum the option 
set `-s escape-time NUMBER`
but this doesn't seem to fit, I've still a too short delay with `NUMBER=0` or `NUMBER=500`..

Any idea? Thanks for reading me!

(I work with debian buster, by the way)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (I too use vi-mode), and I fixed it with `bindkey`.

If you run that command, it lists a lot of unusual binds that you may not expect.  You might find one related to the keystrokes that you are using.

My issue/delay was search related, so the solution was to put this (removal) line in my `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -r '\e/'
```

Comment: Interesting, I will see that this week and tell you how it works, thanks!